# Servicenow - Linked Server passing formatted current date in Openquery

Tags: sql-server, servicenow, openquery

I have connected our ServiceNow database as a linked server to MS SQL Server through an ODBC connector. I am running a query everyday by manually entering the date, now I want to automate this process so I am trying to pass CURRENT_DATE in where clause but I am having issues in passing the date in the following format (Ex 2020-04-02 00:00:00), I used DATE_FORMAT to format the date but it throws an error
`OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVICENOW" returned message "[SN][ODBC ServiceNow driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Unsupported scalar function:DATE_FORMAT.[10149]`

**The query I run everyday**

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SERVICENOW, 'Select 
closed_at,
number,
opened_at
FROM incident
WHERE opened_at BETWEEN ''2020-04-02 00:00:00'' AND ''2020-04-02 23:59:59'')
```

**Automated query throwing error**

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SERVICENOW, 'Select 
closed_at,
number,
opened_at
FROM incident
WHERE opened_at BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, ''yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00'') AND DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, ''yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59'');
```

Answer (score 0):

DATE_FORMAT and CURRENT_DATE are not a valid SQL Server functions. Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SERVICENOW, 'Select 
closed_at,
number,
opened_at
FROM incident
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, opened_at) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()')
```

Converting to a DATE datatype using the CONVERT() function will strip the time off both the values in opened_at and GETDATE().

Comment: I got the following error on executing the above query.  ```OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SERVICENOW" returned message "[SN][ODBC ServiceNow driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Column:DATE not found.[10125]".```

Comment: What is the database platform and version that your Servicenow database is on?

Comment: I am not sure about ServiceNow database version but I am using MS SQL v18.4

Comment: You need to know what database and version the ServiceNow database is because with OPENQUERY you are sending that query over to be executed on the target server so the syntax needs to be in line with the target. Someone at your company should be able to tell you that. If you are having a hard time tracking that person or information down try a database platform specific system query. If you cycle through the various database platforms at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) it will display those corresponding system queries for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to solve this problem, this is now automated. The underlining ServiceNow database was MySQL.

```
DECLARE @date0 datetime,
        @date1 datetime;

SET @date0 = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00');
SET @date1 = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59');


SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(SERVICENOW, 'Select 
closed_at,
number,
opened_at
FROM incident
WHERE opened_at BETWEEN ''''' + FORMAT(CAST(@date0 as datetime), 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00') + ''''' AND ''''' + FORMAT(CAST(@date1 as datetime), 'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59') + ''''' '')';
```